# Как в качестве аргумента в метод передать другой метод C#

Tags: c#

Необходимо возвести одномерный массив в указанную степень и вывести результат на экран. Исходный массив должен оставаться неизменным.
При указании агрумента в метод для выдачи результата возникает ошибка.

Метод `GetPoweredArray()` предназначен для модификации массива

Метод `PrintArray` предназначен для вывода модифицированного массива без изменения исходного массива.

Прикладываю код:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var arrayToPower = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            PrintArray(GetPoweredArray(arrayToPower, 1));
            PrintArray(GetPoweredArray(arrayToPower, 2));
            PrintArray(GetPoweredArray(arrayToPower, 3));
            PrintArray(GetPoweredArray(new int[0], 1));
            PrintArray(GetPoweredArray(new[] { 42 }, 0));
        }

        public static int[] GetPoweredArray(int[] arr, int power)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                arr[i] *= power;
            }
            return arr;
        }

        static void PrintArray(GetPoweredArray(arr))
        {
            for(int i = 0;i<arr.Length;i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что возводите число в указанную степень, а не просто перемножаете значения массива с некоторым числом? Во-вторых, для чего вам понадобилось подобие callback'а?

Comment: @gregzakharov в главном методе Main ничего менять нельзя, такое задание...

Comment: Какое "такое"? Вы понимаете, что в цикле вы просто перемножаете числа, а не возводите в степень?

Comment: Учить делегаты.

Comment: @aepot извините если кажусь глупой, делегатам в колледже нас еще не учили

Comment: Это всего-лишь ответ, как метод засунуть в аргументы другого метода - с помощью делегата. Вы спросили, я ответил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В заголовке у вас один вопрос, в самом сообщении - другой. Если цель просто возвести в степень, то

1. Если не использовать делегаты, то входящим параметром для `PrintArray` должен быть массив, который требуется распечатать. Результат будет предоставлен методом `GetPoweredArray`
2. `arr[i] *= power;` - тут вы просто умножаете элемент массива на число power, а не возводите в степень.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var arrayToPower = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    PrintArray(GetPoweredArray(arrayToPower, 1));
    PrintArray(GetPoweredArray(arrayToPower, 2));
    PrintArray(GetPoweredArray(arrayToPower, 3));
    PrintArray(GetPoweredArray(new int[0], 1));
    PrintArray(GetPoweredArray(new[] { 42 }, 0));
}

public static int[] GetPoweredArray(int[] arr, int power)
{
    var result = new int[arr.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = (int)Math.Pow(arr[i], power);
    }
    return result;
}

static void PrintArray(int[] arr )
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, вы мне помогли) Я знаю, что возводят в степень иначе, чем я написала, меня больше интересовал вопрос как вывести получившийся результат на экран, передав модифицированный массив, (возведенный в степень) в метод PrintArray.

Comment: Да, кстати у вас на стене есть глава "О метке", там заметила недостающий артикль a. Исправьте пожалуйста. I try to work as a programmer

Answer (score 0):

Укажи в параметрах Func<int[], int, int[]>

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    PrintArray(GetPoweredArray);
}    

static int[] GetPoweredArray(int[] arr, int p) {}

static void PrintArray(Func<int[], int, int[]> fn) { 
    int[] result = fn(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 3);
    //print... 
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Но тогда сами параметры для метода `GetPoweredArray` придется передавать уже внутри `PrintArray`, либо для `PrintArray` добавить параметры `PrintArray(int[], int, Func<int[], int, int[]> fn)`